# implementing EditText like google play music with animation in android

Tags: android, search, android-actionbar, android-animation

I am developing an application in which I need to implement custom search.
I wanted to place the icon on `ActionBar` and have successfully done that.
But not able to animate while opening search box

**res/menu/main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_settings"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/action_settings"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_search"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/layout_search"
        android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_search"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
        android:title="Search"/>

</menu>
```

**res/layout/layout_search**

```
 [![<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <AutoCompleteTextView

        android:id="@+id/autoComplete"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:hint="Search"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:imeOptions="actionDone"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textCursorDrawable="@android:color/black"
        />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I also need to animate the **hamburger** to **back arrow** icon change.

first two screens are what I am getting 
and last two screens are what I am expecting.

[image: here is what I am getting **"1"**]

[image: here is what I am getting **"2"**]

[image: this is what i want]

[image]

Comment: have you try anything?

Comment: I have tried adding background to look like that search box
but I am not getting how do i apply animation while expanding/collapsing the search layout.

Comment: Are you using toolbar or actionbar?

Comment: for animation reference, you can refer Google play music or google play movies

Comment: I am using ActionBar

Comment: use toolbar instead of action bar the images you show in question is used toolbar.